# Setting process DPI awareness so that the system compensates for scaling factors

Tags: winapi, windows-10, mouse-hook, mouse-coordinates, dpi-aware

I have the following mouse hook procedure (simplified for the explanation).

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, mouseHookProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0) ;

LRESULT mouseHookProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    if(code==HC_ACTION){
        const auto& data = *(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam ;
        
        data.pt ; //This point gives physical coordinates. It ignores the monitor's scaling factor.
        //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-msllhookstruct
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam) ;
}
```

The mouse coordinates I get from the hook are not adjusted by the monitor's scaling factor.
Whether I set my monitor's scaling factor to 100% or 200%, the mouse hook always gives me physical pixels.

On the other hand, the `GetCursorPos` winapi function gives the coordinates in logical pixels. i.e. If the scaling factor is 200%, `GetCursorPos` will give the coordinates divided by 2, whereas the mouse hook will give the numbers unadjusted.

According to this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/ne-shellscalingapi-process_dpi_awareness

if a program is **NOT** DPI-aware, the system compensates the scaling factor so that the program keeps working as if nothing happened.

That's exactly what's happening with the returned value of `GetCursorPos`. It's giving logical pixels rather than physical ones.

The mouse hook procedure, on the other hand, is not being adjusted by the system.

I tried setting my program as DPI-unaware in the manifest, with this:

```
<asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
        <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">unaware</dpiAwareness>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
</asmv3:application>
```

But it makes no difference.
I also tried declaring it as DPI-aware, with this:

```
<asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
        <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>
        <dpiAware>True/PM</dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
</asmv3:application>
```

And that, also, made no difference.

Is there any setting I can add to my program, either via the manifest or otherwise, that will make the mouse hook procedure to give logical coordinates as `GetCursorPos` does?

I'm testing all this in Windows 10.

---

**FOLLOW UP:**

I found the problem. My manifest file was incorrect. The XML namespaces were not set properly.

Here is the one that works.

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3"> 
    <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="AppName" type="win32"/>
    <asmv3:application>
        <asmv3:windowsSettings>
            <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2,PerMonitor</dpiAwareness>
            <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">True/PM</dpiAware>
        </asmv3:windowsSettings>
    </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

In order for the system to give logical coordinates to a program, the program has to be DPI-aware.
Programs that don't manifest DPI-awareness will handle coordinates inconsistently all over, not just in the mouse hook, also in BitBlt, IAccesibility, UIAutomation, etc.

I don't understand why Microsoft decided to do it backwards. Programs that don't manifest DPI-awareness should behave as usual, not the other way around.

This means that whenever a scaling factor is set on a monitor, most programs will break by default. In order to unbreak them, they have to become DPI-aware and... just like that... they will work again.

Comment: A low-level mouse hook runs before the system has even started to determine the target window. Consequently, the system cannot apply any sort of virtualization to the coordinates.

Answer (score -1):

**I don't understand why Microsoft decided to do it backwards. Programs that don't manifest DPI-awareness should behave as usual, not the other way around.**

In fact, Microsoft's doc explains this problem.

From [High DPI Desktop Application Development on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows),

> Desktop applications using older Windows programming technologies (raw
> Win32 programming, Windows Forms, Windows Presentation Framework
> (WPF), etc.) are unable to automatically handle DPI scaling without
> additional developer work. Without such work, applications will appear
> blurry or incorrectly-sized in many common usage scenarios.

If you want to avoid DPI awareness problems, please create a `UWP` application.

> To start, if you're creating a new Windows app from scratch, it is
> highly recommended that you create a [Universal Windows Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide) (UWP)
> application. UWP applications automatically—and dynamically—scale for
> each display that they're running on.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't even attempt to address the question. Clearly, calling [SetWindowsHookEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) is restricted to desktop applications only. Telling the OP to write a UWP application, just so they won't run into DPI awareness issues, is not helpful. On top of missing the point, that a low-level mouse hook is completely outside the DPI-awareness business. And to top it all off, recommending UWP in face of [Project Reunion](https://github.com/microsoft/ProjectReunion) is a bit hard to digest.